# How to get extras form intent when Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT?

Tags: android

I put in my broadcast receiver for action ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT

```
if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT)){
       for(String k : intent.getExtras().keySet()){
        Log.d("arek","klucz = "+k);
        Log.v("arek","wartość= "+intent.getExtras().get(k).toString());
 }
```

and get in logs:

```
05-10 15:13:33.871: D/arek(10322): klucz = storage_volume
05-10 15:13:33.871: V/arek(10322): wartość= StorageVolume [mStorageId=131073 mPath=/storage/extSdCard mDescriptionId=17041195 mPrimary=false mRemovable=true mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 mAllowMassStorage=false mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null mSubSystem=sd mActivitySecureContainer=false]
05-10 15:13:33.881: I/arek(10322): mStorageManager.getVolume(filePath).getStorageId() = 131073
```

but where is defined string for key: storage_volume

because I want to do:

```
StorageVolume sv = (StorageVolume) intent.getExtras().get("storage_volume");
```

So where is defined constant value with string "storage_volume"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `android.os.storage.StorageVolume.EXTRA_STORAGE_VOLUME`. But this class itself is hidden.

See [StorageVolume.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.java).